# function with msg.sender does not return address

Tags: solidity, contract-development, addresses

Function returns null address in any case.

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.9;

contract Test {

    address da;
    function getSender () constant returns (address){
        da=msg.sender;
        return da;
    }
}
```

Tried through myetherwallet and parity, network is not synchronized.

Comment: I've tested your code and the function getSender() correctly returns the address.

Comment: In your code you are storing `msg.sender` in the variable `da`, such function cannot be constant because your are modifying the contract state.

Comment: Why not just `return msg.sender;` ?

Comment: Do I need an ether on the contract to perform this function?

Answer (score 1):

In a query function you are trying to update contract state variable.
You can return msg.sender without using any variables

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.9;

contract Test {
    address da;
    function getSender () constant returns (address){
        return msg.sender; // just return msg.sender
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You either return msg.sender without updating "da" state variable so it's truly a constant function, or you don't make it constant but you'll have to get the return value out of an event if you want to access it.

Constant/view functions can't modify state variables in any way.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the msg.sender to da in the constructor and than just return da with the modifier View.

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.9;

contract Test {

    address da;

    function Test() public {
        da = msg.sender;
    }

    function getSender () public view returns (address){
        return da;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can update a state variable, or you can make the function read-only (with `constant`, `view` or `pure`), but you can't do both. I've upvoted three answers that say it differently and offer different approaches depending on what you need it to do.

```
pragma solidity 0.4.9;

contract DA {

    address public da;

    function DA() public {
        da = msg.sender;
    }

    function setDa() public returns(bool success) {
        da = msg.sender;
        return true;
    }

    // getDa() is not really needed because da is made `public` near line 5, so function da() does the same.

    function getDa() public constant returns (address){
        return da;
    }

    function getMsgSender() public constant returns(address) {
        return msg.sender;
    }
}
```

Hope it helps.